# Set selected option via hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, html-select

I want to set the selected option of 2 select inputs from a hyperlink. This forms part of a shopping cart where I show if there is an item in stock and if there is, the user can click it. This sets the values of the corresponding options. This works fine for size when it's whole numbers (doesn't work for 4.5) and it doesn't set the value of the fitting.

I've put the code on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/G6Mz5/

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may a simpler way, but this is based on the code you already had in your fiddle:

```
$('.instock').bind({
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr('rel').split(',');

        $('#size').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === data[0];  
        }).attr('selected',true);
        $('#fitting').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === data[1];  
        }).attr('selected',true);
    }
});
```

This gets all the `option` elements and then filters them to leave only the ones which match the current text.

Here's an [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/G6Mz5/5/).

Comment: This works perfectly on the fiddle but not on my page (internal site).  hmmm Best answer so far, let me check my page and get back to you. Thanks James.

Comment: Conflicting element called #fitting was causing the problem. Now fixing internally. Thanks for you help. Close call between this and Rusty Jeans but have got this working. Think the other method should work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.instock').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).attr('rel').split(',');


            $('#size').find('option:contains("' + data[0].toString() + '")').attr('selected',true);
            $('#fitting').find('option:contains("' + data[1].toString() + '")').attr('selected',true);
        }
    });
```

I have tested it on your jsfiddle link, its working now

Comment: The only problem is that where I have 4 and 4.5, I don't get the correct one. Contains 4 both times IYSWIM?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `val()` of the select to the one you want.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/tclayson/kE4c5/

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<a href="#" id="clicked">Click</a>
```

When you click on the link "click" it just sets the value of the select (#mySelect) to 2.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clicked').click(function(){
        $('#mySelect').val('2');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Therefore instead of trying to `find()` the option you want to set to selected, you can just change the select based on the values of the options (eg: 4.5 will be 46 in your case).

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know the value to set in my <a>, only the text of the option.

Comment: hmm fair enough - odd problem you have there then! :/ sorry I can't help

Answer (score 0):

The period is a special character and it needs to be escaped by two back slashes. Try this:

```
$('#size').find('option[text=' + data[0].toString().replace(".", "\\.") + ']').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it's my page. Must have a conflicting element somewhere